# Scaling performance issues with MongoDB Node.JS system design on AWS EC2

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-ec2, horizontal-scaling

I am working on a scaling project with MongoDB on AWS. **I wonder how can I improve my current performance issues?** My goal is to reach about 5000 clients per second while maintaining an average response time of 2000ms, 0 error rate, 0 timeout, and without using AWS Auto Scaling so that I can learn about horizontal and vertical scaling.

In one AWS EC2 instance, I deploy my MongoDB database with 10 millions unique product_id. In another EC2 instance, I deploy one service to connect with the database, here is my loader.io result:
[image: loader io test result 2]
The diagram shows that when I set a get request test where 225 requests are made every second for a minute, the error rate and timeout are 0, and the average response time is 1941ms, which is close to my target of 2000ms. If I set anything higher, the average response time could go over the 2000ms limit, which is not what I want.

Then I began to create another EC2 instance for Nginx load balancer and 2 more instances for the services to horizontal scale my project. I was hoping to get around 600-700 clients per second with the average response time of 2000ms, 0 error rate, and 0 timeout. Unfortunately, these are my results:
[image: loader io 280 test setup]
[image: loader io 280 test result]
[image: loader io 300 test result]
When I look at the loader.io results, it shows that when I set 280 requests per second, the average response time is 186ms, which is much faster than what I have tested previously without Nginx setup. The error rate and timeout are also 0. However, when I set to 300 requests per second, it starts to build err rate and there are about 269 responses with 500 error codes. This is not good.
[image: aws cpu usage 2]
When I look at the AWS Cloudwatch result, I noticed that the CPU usage is pretty low. So I don't have a CPU issue.
[image: New Relic Result 1]
[image: New Relic Result 2]
When I look at the New Relic result, I realize that majority of the response time comes from "MongoDB products toArray", which is the shaded area in brown. Therefore, I need to figure out how to improve the database. **However, I am not sure how to improve that.**

Please note that I did not use "MongoDB products toArray" anywhere in my coding script, it is provided by New Relic. I think what it means is that based on my current query which I have used "find" as a query, it would return an array as a result. If I use "findOne" as my query, it would return an object instead.

My GET request query that I tested:

```
const getReviewByProductId = (data, callback) => {
    const id = parseInt(data.params.id);
    Model.ProductModel.find({ product_id: id }, (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            return callback(err);
        } else {
            return callback(null, results);
        }
    });
}
```

The product_id that this function tests is an unique id. So I don't think indexing would speed up. I am not sure how to improve "MongoDB products toArray".

The following is the nginx.conf:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    upstream nodejs {
    server 13.57.191.130:3000;
    server 204.236.161.63:3000;
    server 18.216.89.77:3000;
    }
    server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
    proxy_pass http://nodejs;
    }
  }
}
```

This is the basic setup of Nginx that I used. Please let me know if there is anything that can improve the performance related to "MongoDB products toArray".

This is my MongoDB schema in case interested:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(`${process.env.MONGO_HOST}/reviews`, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useCreateIndex: true });
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const productSchema = new Schema({
    product_id: { type: Number, required: true, unique: true },
    product_name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    review: [{
        review_id: { type: Number, required: true, unique: true },
        user: {
            user_id: { type: Number },
            firstname: { type: String },
            lastname: { type: String },
            gender: { type: String, enum: ['Male', 'Female', 'Other'] },
            nickname: { type: String },
            email: { type: String, required: true },
            password: { type: String, required: true },
        },
        opinion: { type: String, required: true },
        text: { type: String },
        rating_overall: { type: Number, min: 1, max: 5, required: true },
        doesRecommended: { type: Boolean, required: true },
        rating_size: { type: String, enum: ['a size too small', '1/2 a size too small', 'Perfect', '1/2 a size too big', 'a size too big'], required: true },
        rating_width: { type: String, enum: ['Too narrow', 'Slightly narrow', 'Perfect', 'Slightly wide', 'Too wide'], required: true },
        rating_comfort: { type: String, enum: ['Uncomfortable', 'Slightly uncomfortable', 'Ok', 'Comfortable', 'Perfect'], required: true },
        rating_quality: { type: String, enum: ['Poor', 'Below average', 'What I expected', 'Pretty great', 'Perfect'], required: true },
        isHelpful: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 },
        isNotHelpful: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 },
        created_at: { type: Date, required: true },
        review_photo_path: [{
            review_photo_id: { type: Number },
            review_photo_url: { type: String }
        }]
    }]
});
const ProductModel = mongoose.model('product', productSchema);
module.exports = { ProductModel };
```

My database is currently running `t2.medium` on EC2 and my services and Nginx are running on `t2.micro` on EC2.

Here is [the project in Github](https://github.com/hongkongbboy/Adidas_Clone-System_Design_Scaling_Project). I plan to deploy more services instances and add to the Nginx load balancer, but at the current moment, I want to fix the "MongoDB products toArray" response time issue first.

Comment: What is "MongoDB products toArray" exactly?

Comment: Thanks for the response. "MongoDB products toArray" is not something that I used anywhere in my code. It is actually provided by NewRelic if you look at one of the New Relic diagrams above with brown shaded color. I think what it means is that based on current mongoDB get query, it would return an array as a result because I use "find". This array always has a length of one btw. If I change to "findOne", I believe it would return an object as a result. I will update the content above to clarify for other readers.

Comment: While you can improve the query execution *performance*, this does not necessarily affect *scalability*. When you say "cpu usage" that is an application graph, yes? How is the database doing on cpu?